# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger

Tags: java, spring, maven, slf4j

I'm facing a problem when I want to build my Spring project. The error that I'm getting from eclipse is:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectServer]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectServer]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2509)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
    ... 20 more

Apr 24, 2016 8:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 6 more

Apr 24, 2016 8:11:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1128)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 11 more
```

---

My pom file is configured like this :

> ```
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
>   <artifactId>projectServer</artifactId>
>   <version>0.4</version>
>   <packaging>war</packaging>
>
>   <properties>
>
>       <!-- Generic properties -->
>       <java.version>1.6</java.version>
>       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>       <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
>
>       <!-- Web -->
>       <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
>       <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
>       <servlet.version>4.0.0-b01</servlet.version>
>
>
>       <!-- Spring -->
>       <spring-framework.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
>       <spring-security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
>
>       <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
>       <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
>
>       <!-- Logging -->
>       <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
>       <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
>
>       <!-- Test -->
>       <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
>
>   </properties>
>
>   <dependencies>
>
>       <!-- Spring MVC -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <!-- Spring security -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
>           <version>${jstl.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
>           <version>${jsp.version}</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
>           <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
>           <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
>           <scope>compile</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
>           <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
>           <version>${logback.version}</version>
>           <scope>runtime</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Hibernate -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>           <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
>           <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!--Json Simple -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
>           <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
>           <version>1.1.1</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Mysql -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>           <version>5.1.38</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Test Artifacts -->
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>           <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
>           <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>junit</groupId>
>           <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>           <version>${junit.version}</version>
>           <scope>test</scope>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <!-- Tomcat -->
>       <!-- <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
>           <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
>           <version>7.0.67</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
>           <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
>           <version>7.0.67</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
>           <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
>           <version>7.0.67</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
>           <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
>           <version>7.0.67</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
>           <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
>           <version>4.5.1</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency> -->
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.impetus.client</groupId>
>           <artifactId>kundera-cassandra</artifactId>
>           <version>2.9</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
>           <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
>           <version>2.1</version>
>       </dependency>
>
>   </dependencies>
> </project>
> ```

I tried every solution that I found in stackoverflow, but no result.

Thank you in advance for your help
regards

Comment: You should remove the `<scope>compile</scope>` from `slf4j` (you need it at runtime too).

Comment: why `<scope>compile</scope>` for `slf4j' ?

Comment: I removed <scope>compile</scope>, but I m facing the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add another dependency to solve the issue.

```
  <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Add another dependency. Hope it will help you.